# Surface Flux Integral Across a Circular Surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

I need to calculate
$$
\iint_S \textbf{J}\cdot\hat{\textbf{n}}\; dS
$$
Where S is the circular surface centered at the origin, area $A$, in the $yz$-plane, with unit normal having a negative $x$-component.

$$\textbf{J} = -\sigma\nabla\phi(\textbf{r}), \;\; \phi(\textbf{r}) = V(1-x/L)$$

What I'm struggling with here is getting a parametric representation of this surface for this integral in terms of u and v. I can very easily parametrise the curve of the boundary of this surface but obviously for this integral I need a representation of the surface.
I tried:

$$
S:\; (u,v) \rightarrow \; \left(v, \sqrt\frac{A}{\pi}\cos(u), \sqrt\frac{A}{\pi}\sin(u)\right) \;\;
0\leq u\leq 2\pi, \; v = 0
$$

But then calculating the normal, $\textbf{v}_{u} \times \textbf{v}_{u}$, I get a normal to the cylinder with this circle as it's end. I know I need to get $(-1, 0, 0)$ as my unit normal vector.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A parametrization of the disk S is
$$S:\; (u,v) \rightarrow \; \left(0, v\cos(u), v\sin(u)\right) \;\;\text{with}\;\;
0\leq u\leq 2\pi, \; 0\leq v \leq \sqrt\frac{A}{\pi}.$$
Then
$$\textbf{S}_{u} \times \textbf{S}_{v}=\left(0, -v\sin(u), v\cos(u)\right) \times \left(0, \cos(u), \sin(u)\right)=(-v,0,0)\implies \textbf{n}=(-1,0,0).$$

Actually, you don't need it, because
$$\textbf{J} = -\sigma\nabla(V(1-x/L))=-\sigma(-V/L,0,0)$$
is constant and therefore
$$\iint_S \textbf{J}\cdot\hat{\textbf{n}}\; dS=-\sigma(-V/L,0,0)\cdot(-1,0,0)A=\frac{\sigma VA}{L}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, this is fab! I understand the way I'm supposed to parameterise a disc now! Although, for the final integral calculation have you made a minus sign error? I got the negative of what you have.

Answer (score 2):

Since your surface is contained in the $y,z$ plane, you can use $y$ and $z$ as the parameters, although you'll have to stick a minus sign in there somewhere to get the correct normal vector.

So how about $(u,v) \mapsto (0,-u,v)$ with $-1 \le u \le +1$ and $-\sqrt{1-u^2} \le v \le \sqrt{1-u^2}$.